# Any Eclipse plugin to show Mercurial diff of file in editor?

Tags: eclipse, mercurial

Plugins like [vim-signify](https://github.com/mhinz/vim-signify) for Vim show the diff status of the file being edited, if the file belongs to a Mercurial or Git repository. It displays this information by showing indicators for the lines which have changed since last commit, along the left gutter of the editor window.

Is there any similar **plugin** for **Eclipse** which works with **Mercurial**? That is, while editing a file which belongs to a Mercurial repository, the lines which have changed are highlighted or indicated by some means.

Answer (score 1):

The one and only one worth it :) : https://bitbucket.org/mercurialeclipse/main/wiki/Home